# How To Place Two Images Side By Side In Header

Tags: html, css, image, header, alignment

I need to place two images next to each other in the header. One is a logo and one is a banner image - the logo is a link back to the home page. The header has the background-color red, so once the banner is added, most of the header will be hidden except for a thin line of red at the bottom. I tried this:

CSS:

```
div.container {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<header>
<div class="container">
<a href="index.html><img class="logo" src="images/logo.jpg" height="110"
width="200"></a>
</div>
<div class="container">
<img class="banner" src="images/banner.jpg" height="110" width="800">
</div>
```

But it did not work. Here is a screenshot showing the web page. The Banner should go just to the right of the logo "Sean's"[image]

After trying this:

```
div.container {
display:inline-block;
Width:auto!important;
}
```

[image]

Link to full HTML, CSS, and Javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/HappyHands31/kzbvLheq/

Comment: Please, provide more information(jsfiddle and etc).

Comment: link to jsfiddle with entire code: http://jsfiddle.net/5v2a317d/

Comment: Here is correct link: http://jsfiddle.net/HappyHands31/kzbvLheq/

Comment: Is that solution didn't worked out well?

Comment: Yes. This is the code that works:

https://jsfiddle.net/HappyHands31/kzbvLheq/ 

But the page must be open wide enough for both pictures to fit on the same line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The width of images(`.banner` and `.logo`) are bigger than their parent(`header`) so the  `.banner` goes to the second line. you can reduce the size of `.banner`(for example 200)

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/kzbvLheq/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this out, hopefully this will resolve your issue..
If you still face any problem, please show the entire code or URL

```
div.container {
  display:inline-block;
  Width:auto!important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in this line of code:

```
<a href="index.html>
```

You forgot to close the quotation marks after the `href` tag. You should replace it with

```
<a href="index.html">
```

Otherwise, your code works fine.

Full Code: (Note Change in Line 3)

```
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <a href="index.html"><img class="logo" src="images/logo.jpg" height="110"
        width="200"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <img class="banner" src="images/banner.jpg" height="110" width="800">
    </div>
</header>
```

Another suggestion that I do have for you is to make the images `inline-block` instead of putting a container div around them. It works the same way and you have less elements in your code.

**CSS**

```
img {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5v2a317d/

Comment: As far as closing the quotation marks, that was just a typo as I transfered the code from my text editor to here. 

Your

    img {
           display: inline-block;
    }

suggestion worked. Thank you!